# Simpler way to get multiple bytes from a string?

Tags: javascript, html, string

Simple problem, but my current solution is too bulky.

I have a string "data" and I want to add selected bytes of it to another string "piece".

```
var piece = data[k]
piece += data[k+1]+data[k+2]+data[k+3]+data[k+4]+data[k+5]+data[k+6]+data[k+7]+data[k+8]+data[k+9]+data[k+10]+data[k+11]+data[k+12]+data[k+13]+data[k+14]+data[k+15]
```

where k is an interger.

Is there a way to have "piece" contain bits from k to k+15 of "data" without adding each one manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a string `piece` that contains the 16 bits from `k` to `k+15` try:

```
var piece = data.slice(k, k+16);
```

Keep in mind, [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) extracts up to (but not including) the end position.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method of String:

```
var piece = data.slice(0, 15);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely too bulky.  This is slimmer:

```
var piece = data.slice(k, k + 15);
```